# How to validate tinyMCE popup textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

Please any one help me. I need the tinyMCE popup textbox validation. how to validate the textbox when click on ok Here i use the code below.

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('weblink', function(editor, url) {
    editor.addButton('weblink', {
        text: 'Web Link',
        icon: false,        
        onclick: function() {
            editor.windowManager.open({
                title: 'Web Link',
                body: [
                {type: 'textbox', name: 'caption', label: 'Enter Your Caption',maxLength:20},
                {type: 'textbox', name: 'weburl', label: 'Enter Your Web URL',maxLength:32}
                ],
                onsubmit: function(e){
                    var weblinkTxt  =   "href='"+e.data.weburl+"'";

                        if(hyperlink!='' && (hyperlink==1 || hyperlink =='1'))
                        {
                            editor.insertContent("<a "+weblinkTxt+">"+ e.data.caption+"</a>")
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            editor.insertContent("<img src='"+emailImg+"'>"+ e.data.caption+" "+e.data.weburl)
                        }

                }
            });
        }
    });  
});
```

Comment: Please format you code properly. Did you try using `tinymce.triggerSave();` on form submit

Answer (score 6):

I just came across the need to validate the input from a dialog in TinyMCE as well. Unfortunately, it seems there is no native way to do it. However, I found a way to do it, using `e.preventDefault()`.

The idea is to use the `e.preventDefault()` right after the submit function starts, and manage the dialog window afterwards. This way, it is possible to validate the input:

- If it is not valid, then show a warning to the user and do nothing to the dialog window. It will be kept open, and the user will have to insert a new value;
- If it is valid, then close the window dialog and continue the method to do whatever you want.

Applied to you example, it would be like this:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('weblink', function(editor, url) {
    editor.addButton('weblink', {
        text: 'Web Link',
        icon: false,        
        onclick: function() {
            editor.windowManager.open({
                title: 'Web Link',
                body: [
                {type: 'textbox', name: 'caption', label: 'Enter Your Caption',maxLength:20},
                {type: 'textbox', name: 'weburl', label: 'Enter Your Web URL',maxLength:32}
                ],
                onsubmit: function(e){
                    //this will prevent TinyMCE from closing the window dialog
                    e.preventDefault();

                    /*here you apply your validations to e.data.weburl
                      and to e.data.caption*/

                    if(isNotValid){
                        /*The validation failed, so let's tell the user about it.
                          The empty function is to let TinyMCE know that it should
                          do nothing when clicking on the "OK" button. Without it,
                          I experienced different behaviour when clicking on
                          "OK" and when pressing "Enter".*/
                        editor.windowManager.alert('Invalid input!', function(){});
                    } else {
                        /*It is valid, so let's first close the
                          dialog window, and then do what you want*/
                        editor.windowManager.close();

                        var weblinkTxt  =   "href='"+e.data.weburl+"'";

                        if(hyperlink!='' && (hyperlink==1 || hyperlink =='1'))
                        {
                            editor.insertContent("<a "+weblinkTxt+">"+ e.data.caption+"</a>")
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            editor.insertContent("<img src='"+emailImg+"'>"+ e.data.caption+" "+e.data.weburl)
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });  
});
```

Hope this can still help you or anyone also facing this problem!

Comment: Works great, thank you. Another approach would be to call e.preventDefault() only if the input is invalid. Default behavior will take over whenever the data is indeed valid.